# EditText onFocusChangeListener error on detaching Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-edittext

**Background**

Hi all, I have a function called `checkEmailAvailability` that sends `HTTP` request when the focus is out of `EmailEditText` (basically I wanted to `checkEmailAvailability` when the user is done typing).

Based on the result of the function I show or hide an error textView called `errorTextView`.

**The Problem**

I am using the following method to handle focus change and checking for email availability.

```
EmailEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener { view, hasFocus ->
            if (!hasFocus){
                checkEmailAvailability()
            }else{
                canRegisterEmail = false
                emailAvailabilityCheckDone = false
            }
        }
```

Everything works fine, except when the focus is on `EmailEditText` and I go to another `fragment`, again the  `checkEmailAvailability()` gets called and since I am already outside of this `fragment` and the function tries to hide/show the `errorTextView`, the app crashes with an error:

```
errorTextView must not be null
```

How can I stop to check onFocusChange when the fragment is going to be closed or what would you suggest to prevent this crash?

Comment: Simple solution is to add `if(errorTextView != null)` check in your code, it will prevent these crashes. More elegant one would use `Fragment#isRemoving()` to check whether you fragment is being removed from the activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this solution

**Declare this variable**

```
  private var isFragment_visible: Boolean = false;
```

then in `onCreateView()`

```
 isFragment_visible=true
```

and in `onDestroyView()`

```
 isFragment_visible=false
```

Now use this variable

```
EmailEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener { view, hasFocus ->
            if (!hasFocus&&isFragment_visible){
                checkEmailAvailability()
            }else{
                canRegisterEmail = false
                emailAvailabilityCheckDone = false
            }
        }
```

Comment: This worked for me, except that had to set the Boolean to false in onPause (and true in onCreateView and onResume), as the listener gets called before onDestroyView.

Answer (score 0):

try writing the listener in the onViewCreated and accessing the editText as view.editText